# Unable to call spring boot application service when deployed to tomcat server.

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, spring-boot, gradle

I have a SpringBootApp that I can run in eclipse by right-clinging and then selecting Run as -> Java Application. However, when I build a .war file and deploy it to my tomcat server. The console looks as though the application should have deployed but I'm unable to hit my rest services. I'm getting a 404 error. I really have no clue why it is not working so if anyone knows a solution could you explain why... Also, when I look in my war file i see all the classes files needed to deploy the application. 
You can download the code [github.](https://github.com/SomeoneFromSomewhere/SampleSpringBoot)

**Controller**:

```
package com.sample.pkg;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@ComponentScan("com.sample.pkg")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    SampleComponent component;

    @RequestMapping("/sendOption")
    public String update(@RequestParam(value = "option") String option) {
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("option1")) {
            component.updateStatus(true);
            return "Something was updated";
        } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("option2")) {
            component.updateStatus(false);
            return "Something else was updated";
        }
        return "You have entered in an option that is invalid. Please enter a valid option.";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getOption")
    public String control() {

        if (component.getStatus()) {
            return "option1";
        } else if (!component.getStatus()) {
            return "option2";
        }
        return "error";
    }

}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.chicken.door;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}  

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Output:

```
2017-07-18 21:32:13.246  INFO 947 --- [           main] com.sample.pkg.Application               : Started Application in 10.6 seconds (JVM running for 10.976)
```

Comment: Having a quick look at your project's code, you have to fix few things before proceeding:
1) Application.java: remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` & `@PropertySource`
2) SampleConfig.java is empty? Don't forget to use `@Configuration`
3) Delete application.properties under /src/main/java/com/sample/pkg/
4) SampleEntity.java: use `@EmbeddedId` instead of `@Id`
5) SampleController.java: remove `@ComponentScan`
6) No need for the extra SampleComponent.java, use the service directly from the controller.

Comment: How you are accessing the controller. The external tomcat server will get the name of your war file as context root. so your controller url should be http://localhost:{portno}/gs-spring-boot/getOption